# How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

I want to create a transparent Activity on top of another activity.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1491, accepted):

Add the following style in your `res/values/styles.xml` file (if you don’t have one, create it.) Here’s a complete file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

(The value `@color/transparent` is the color value `#00000000` which I put in the `res/values/color.xml` file. You can also use `@android:color/transparent` in later Android versions.)

Then apply the style to your activity, for example:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: I used `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Comment: Great! Just one improvement:
If you use 
parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
you will get the exactly behaviour of a dialog. That means fading in/out instead of sliding in/out (like an activity)

Comment: Will the background be clickable? can I click on the former activity that is shown?

Comment: As @Emilio mentioned this will behave like a dialog, mainly because of `android:windowIsFloating` set to true. Remove this property to behave like a normal activity (in this case it will match `android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`)

Comment: How do I also make it so it's behind the current Activity? It's transparent on top of an Activity at the moment and it can't respond to touch events..

Comment: @Neeta, I don't understand your request. This is an activity even though it's transparent, so it gets its own touch events. Also, what is the benefit of having a transparent activity behind the current one? I think you might be looking for something else. You should probably post what you would like to do as a different question.

Comment: @Guy Did you ever figure out the answer to your problem? I'm having the same issue..

Comment: How can I round the corners of the activity screen? @marek-sebera

Comment: I removed <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item> to have a fullscreen & transparent activity

Comment: @KiemDuong If I remember correctly on older devices android:windowIsFloating was required in order to not show the title of the window. I'm not sure, though. You should test any changes to this code on older devices/emulators if you care about them.

Comment: When I try this code on an android 4.2 device, the entire background is black, instead of transparent. Anyone had that issue?

Comment: @ch3rryc0ke You're doing something wrong. It definitely works for me on my 4.2 Galaxy Nexus. Maybe your theme is overriding the color values, or maybe you entered wrong values for colors.

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to set the theme programmatically using this.SetTheme(..) in onCreate. For this particular transparent theme, that doesn't work-- you get all black. Once you set the theme in XML, then it works.

Comment: @gnobal: I was following this question answer to create a transparent activity, My buttons, textviews which I have placed in the top of the xml file which I want to be transparent it comes to the center of the screen when I test it on the device.

Comment: @Dibya sorry, but I can't help. You should probably open a new question showing your layout and a screenshot of the issue

Comment: Why not just simply use `android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` ?

Comment: @xmenW.K. This isn't the same as a transparent activity

Comment: @gnobal I used this and it worked great. But I need my screen to be "WAKE UP" which was working fine, but if I apply this style my flags doesn't seems to work: (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)

Comment: @Laggel Sorry, but I can't explain what you're seeing. Maybe see Emilio and aromero comments above

Comment: @gnobal I just commented "<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>" and the screen is waking up again.

Comment: this indeed makes the activity transparent but also changes the appearance of the views...for example an EditText which normally is an invisible box with a blue line at the bottom becomes a distinct rectangle without the blue line. How do i keep the original style of the views ?

Comment: I just created a simple project based on this solution on GitHub. You can check it here: https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/TransparentActivity

Comment: My activity was derived from `AppCompatActivity`. So `parent="android:Theme"` was crashing my app. I just removed it and it worked like charm. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get a ProgressDialog to appear when I use this... Does anybody know why? I am not calling setContentView either... could that be it?

Comment: it would appear that the actual key is setting `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Comment: It is useful too: <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.9</item>

Comment: @Atul You need to use `parent="Theme.AppCompat"` if your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: I removed <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item> to have a fullscreen & transparent activity and if your activity is AppCompactActivity then use Theme.AppCompact
if don't want ActionBar then Theme.AppCompact.NoActionBar

Comment: @vishalpatel as you can see, the original answer was written in 2010. It's amazing that it managed to stay relevant for so many years. Why don't you post whatever works for you as the answer. But... make sure it works backwards on all previous versions that are still used by, let's say.. more than 5 percent of the people (like I did :). Good luck!

Comment: If you're using the AppCompatActivity extend `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` otherwise you'll get a title indicating the title in the middle of the screen.

Comment: For AppCompatActivity, `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`

Comment: need help here https://stackoverflow.com/q/66533461/14046751

Comment: @Room13 Comment we have to incorporate along with the suggested changes.

Answer (score 206):

It goes like this:

```
<activity android:name=".usual.activity.Declaration" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: could you please guide in bit detail???? i am new to android...
where to place it in manifest file and other java files i will create as it is how will i associate it???

Comment: You just add the theme as alex has posted to your activity declaration in the manifest - this bit android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar, for each Activity you can assign it the Translucent theme

Comment: can you tell me how can i transparent activity 50%? becase this is 100% and i need 50%

Comment: In the layout xml of the activity that goes on top just use the alpha channel of the color part to set the transparancey level. Ie. #ff000000 would be 100% black and #AA000000 would make it slightly transparent.

Comment: @user1129443: `50% black should be #7f000000`.

Each component (A, R, G, B) can take values from `0-255`. `50% of 255 = 127. 127 in Hex = 7F` That how to calculate transparency (opacity)

Comment: This method kind of locks the UI as the activity is running but since it is set to translucent,One cannot do anything.Is there a way to avoid this UI locking.

Comment: @yanchenko Unfortunately this is not a good solution. As Akhil says, it locks up the UI!

Comment: This is confusing. what its actually dose is making the activity transparent and block the ui ! 
If some one looking for activity without ui at all then use this:
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`

Answer (score 151):

In the styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#33000000</item> <!-- Or any transparency or color you need -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".WhateverNameOfTheActivityIs"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: If you are planning on actually displaying something on this Activity (say a Dialog or DialogFragment), you'll notice that everything is Dark themed. So you may want your theme to inherit from `Theme.Appcompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead.

Comment: in my case it showing black background.I have parent theme set something else but on one particular activity I am changing theme as mentioned.Any help?

Comment: Works great when I remove "android:background"

Comment: i think you want to remove `background` and put your preferred semi transparent colour in `windowBackground`

Comment: This should be the answer if your activity is using AppCompatActivity in contrast to @gnobal's answer.

Answer (score 39):

Declare your activity in the manifest like this:

```
 <activity   
     android:name=".yourActivity"    
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

And add a transparent background to your layout.

Comment: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 29):

Assign the translucent theme to the activity that you want to make transparent in the Android manifest file of your project:

```
<activity
    android:name="YOUR COMPLETE ACTIVITY NAME WITH PACKAGE"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: this gives IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 20):

### 2021 facts

Just add

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

You're done.

`windowIsFloating` wrong, this makes an INSET floating window.

`windowContentOverlay` only relates to shadows.

`windowIsTranslucent` is WRONG, it DOES NOT make it so you can see the activity behind. windowIsTranslucent is only relevant if animating transitions.

`backgroundDimEnabled` dims the activity below, BUT, it is completely buggy on different devices. (In some cases, it does nothing unless you are using windowIsFloating; in general the behavior is totally buggy/indeterminate.)

`colorBackgroundCacheHint` is irrelevant except on extremely old devices, the default is null anyway.

Comment: "extremely old devices" - Written 10 years ago, only 2 years after Android launched. I guess devices from 2011 in 2021 must be considered "ancient". lol

Comment: Your solution doesn't do the thing actually. The accepted answer, it's 10 years old but it works find.. just need to extend AppCompat theme instead of Theme..

Comment: The accepted answer is quite wrong, for the reasons explained in the five bullet points here.  (You can, simply, read the doco for each point to get the facts.)

Comment: didn't work, the window ended up with black background.

Comment: @htafoya , I have no idea why it doesn't work for some folks. In Android there's an incredible variety of ways you can "start" a project in terms of themes and setup. So unfortunately I cannot say, and I don't think anyone could; the fact that other approaches work (or don't work) for other people unfortunately is also due to a myriad reasons. Android is tough :/ Nevertheless, the five points mentioned here (straight from the recent doco) are factually correct.

Comment: nvm, it had to do with the theme name not extending Theme. on the first place

Comment: Best answer still in 2024. Works like sharm with Theme.MaterialComponents as base theme. Do not forget set transparent backround also to activity_layout.xml.

Comment: @htafoya so in fact it works perfectly (as the doco says it would).  perhaps you should tap to delete your old comment as it may confuse newcomers

Answer (score 19):

In my case, i have to set the theme on the runtime in java based on some conditions. So I created one theme in style (similar to other answers):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then in Java I applied it to my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String email = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppConstants.REGISTER_EMAIL_INTENT_KEY);
    if (email != null && !email.isEmpty()) {
        // We have the valid email ID, no need to take it from user,
        // prepare transparent activity just to perform bg tasks required for login
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Transparent);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    } else
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);
}
```

Remember one **Important point** here: You must call the `setTheme()` function before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. I missed this point and stucked for 2 hours, thinking why my theme is not reflected at run time.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 16):

I wanted to add to this a little bit as I am a new Android developer as well. The accepted answer is great, but I did run into some trouble. I wasn't sure how to add in the color to the colors.xml file. Here is how it should be done:

#### colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="class_zero_background">#7f040000</color>
     <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

In my original colors.xml file I had the tag "drawable":

```
<drawable name="class_zero_background">#7f040000</drawable>
```

And so I did that for the color as well, but I didn't understand that the "@color/" reference meant look for the tag "color" in the XML. I thought that I should mention this as well to help anyone else out.

Answer (score 16):

I achieved it on 2.3.3 by just adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"` in the activity tag in the manifest.

I don't know about lower versions...

Comment: This works fine for 2.2 also. I just created a simple activity with a listview and it floats ontop of the last activity.

Comment: It was added in API 1, that's not a problem :)

Comment: Do not use `AppCompatActivity` if you're using this.

Comment: works in 7.0 also so its good approach. I modified it to @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Answer (score 9):

In the **onCreate** function, below the **setContentView**, add this line:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: Makes the background to completely BLACK for some reason.

Comment: mine too @SubinSebastian, did anyone find a fix to that?

Answer (score 8):

Just let the activity background image be transparent. Or add the theme in the XML file:

```
<activity android:name=".usual.activity.Declaration" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way that I have found is to set the activity's theme in the AndroidManifest to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"`.

Then in the activity's onCreate method, call `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));`.

Answer (score 7):

in addition to the above answers:

to avoid android Oreo related crash on activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>

<activity
     android:name="xActivity"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent" />
```

Comment: As of 2018, this should be **the best answer**

Comment: gave me a black background on emulator with API 28

Comment: I tried this to fix crash related to setting orientation in android 8.0 but I am still getting IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities request orientation

Comment: Works really well. Tested on Samsung S20 on Android 11. It still shows a black screen on the emulator, but just a slightly dimmed screen otherwise.

Comment: Adding the code below should remove the dim that you get with it being a dialog theme. 
`window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)`

Answer (score 6):

For dialog activity I use this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

But you also need to set your main View in the activity to invisible. Otherwise the background will be invisible while all views in it will be visible.

Comment: Makes the background to completely BLACK

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **`AppCompatActivity`** then add this in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="TransparentCompat" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

In `manifest` file you can add this theme to activity tag like this

```
android:theme="@style/TransparentCompat"
```

for more details read this [article](http://nullpointerbay.com/android-appcompat-design-lib-activity-transparency)

Comment: bro When i use the Above Code the transparent was Working Perfect But it doesnt display the opacity of the previous Artboard it Display the Bg of my Home Screen ( wallpeper Screen ) [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQzd2.jpg][1]][1]


  [1]:

Comment: here is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326191/android-how-to-make-a-custom-layout-as-transparency

Answer (score 3):

I just did two things, and it made my activity transparent. They are below.

1. In the manifest file I just added the below code in the **activity** tag.

   ```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
   ```
2. And I just set the background of the main layout for that activity as "**#80000000**". Like

   ```
   android:background="#80000000"
   ```

It perfectly works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assign it the Translucent theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 2):

### There're two ways:

1. Using Theme.NoDisplay
2. Using Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar

Using `Theme.NoDisplay` will still work… but only on older Android devices. On Android 6.0 and higher, using Theme.NoDisplay without calling `finish()` in `onCreate() (or, technically, before onResume())` will ***crash*** your app. This is why the **recommendation** is to use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, which does not suffer from this **limitation**.”

Answer (score 1):

Note 1:In Drawable folder create test.xml and copy the following code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke android:width="2dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#29000000"
        android:startColor="#29000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

//  Note: Corners and shape is as per your requirement.

//  Note 2:Create xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.09"
            android:gravity="center"
         android:background="@drawable/transperent_shape"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
     </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

All those answers might be confusing, there is a difference between Transparent activity and None UI activity.

Using this:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

Will make the activity transparent but will block the UI.

If you want a None UI activity than use this:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`

Comment: Interesting !. In Non UI Activity case, the UI of previous activity which is visible to the user can be interacted with like button clicks, list view swipe etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to the activity tag in your manifest file that needs to look transparent.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `setContentView(R.layout.mLayout)` from your activity and set theme as `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"`. Check this [link](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-developers-needs-to-be-creative-da032e53a478) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

just put this in style.xml

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

oR Add in Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".usual.activity.Declaration" 
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Along with the [gnobal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/5744335) above solution, I had to set **alpha to 0 in the layout file of that particular activity**, because on certain phone (Redmi Narzo 20 pro running on Android 10) a dialog portion of the screen was showing with the screen that was supposed to be transparent. For some reason the windowIsFloating was causing this issue, but on removing it I wasn't getting the desired output.

**Steps:**

1. Add the following in the style.xml located under res > values > styles.xml

   ```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
      <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
      <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
      <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    </style>
   ```
2. Set the theme of the activity with the above style in
   AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <activity
         android:name=".activityName"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
   ```
3. Open your layout file of the activity on which you applied the above style and set it's alpha value to 0 (`android:alpha="0"`) for the parent layout element.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:alpha="0">

     <WebView        
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:alpha="0"/>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

**Please Note:** You'll have to extend you activity using **Activity()** class and **not AppCompatActivity** for using the above solution.